# Issue in reloading data in Kendo StockChart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am facing issue in reloading the data of Kendo Stock Chart.

```
$('#<chartId>').data('kendoStockChart').dataSource.data(<newData>)
```

Reloading the chart data using the above statement doesn't work as in the JSBin link below:

[Kendo Stockchart example showing the issue](http://jsbin.com/izuyoz/1/edit)

Click on "Refresh chart" button below the chart in this example and notice the series in the top chart disappear.
I tried this on other charts (Pie/Line) and reloading data works fine.

Is there any other way to reload this chart that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the chart is rebound / redrawn successfully but the navigator limits are playing a bad joke with you.

Check [this](http://jsbin.com/izuyoz/4/edit) fiddle without using them.